# usar sentencia mysql COUNT y mostrar en ajax

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Estoy tratando de mostrar el numero de filas en pantalla, no por consola.

Hasta ahora lo que he hecho es consultar la base de datos con una sentencia que me muestra el numero de registros, y ese registro lo convierto en json, asi ajax lo reconoce y mi idea es mostrarlo en un html ese numero de fila. lo que no estoy sabiendo es como mostrar ese numero que me arroja que es el numero de filas. Poder meter ese resultado  en un template +=.

El html es:

```
js

$(document).ready(function () {

                   notificacion();
               


            function notificacion() {

       $.ajax({

             url: "../../model/parcel/notifications.php",
          type: 'GET',
        success: function (response) {
         let notificacion = (response);
        console.log(notificacion);
        let template = "";

          template += `
         <div class="cajita-notificacion" >
        <div class="caja-notificacion"> 
           <span class="info-bd"> <span class="info-titulo">Nueva solicitud de</span> 
       ${notificacion.cuentaDatos}<span>
          </div>
    </div>  
    

      `;        

$("#caja-notificacion").html(template);
   }
  })
  }

 )};
```

El script php es:

```
function notificacion(){

include('../../control/parcel/db.php');


$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM reclute WHERE estado IS NULL;";
$result=mysqli_query($connection,$query);

if(!$result){
    die('Query Failed' . mysqli_error($connection));
}

$num_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$jsonstring=json_encode(['cuentaDatos' => $num_rows]);
echo $jsonstring;
 

    }
     notificacion();
```

y lo que me muestra

```
console.log(notificacion);  {"cuentaDatos":{"0":"1","COUNT(*)":"1"}}
```

y si

```
let notificacion = (response); la reemplazo por---> let notificacion => JSON.parse(response);
```

me arroja un objeto:

```
{cuentaDatos: {…}}
cuentaDatos: {0: "1", COUNT(*): "1"}
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: No te esta trayendo datos revisa el query mysql

Answer (score 3):

Considera hacer lo siguiente:

- Dale un alias al conteo de la consulta así:

  ```
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total FROM tuTabla WHERE estado IS NULL;
  ```
- Ahora al array que transformas a JSON prueba indicarle que acceda a esa clave que le diste al conteo de esta forma:

  ```
  $jsonstring=json_encode(['cuentaDatos' => $num_rows['Total']]);
  ```
- Ahora en la respuesta que obtienes de tu petición AJAX deberías lograr acceder a total de esta forma:

  ```
  let notificacion = (response.cuentaDatos);
  ```

Para que de esta manera el backend este mandando directamente el resultado del conteo y lo puedas leer al momento de acceder a `cuentaDatos` que es la clave que tiene declarada.

Comment: Justo eso estaba escribiendo yo :) Al volcar $num_rows está mandando las dos opciones del array juntas, una con índice [0] y una con índice asociativo ["COUNT(*)"].

Comment: Muy bien, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Hay varios problemas en tu código:

### Usa un método específico

Conviene entender que `mysqli_fetch_array()` te trae el mismo dato **dos veces**, como array asociativo y como array numérico, por eso ves dos veces el mismo valor en la consola:

```
 {"cuentaDatos":{"0":"1","COUNT(*)":"1"}}
```

En una consulta con `N` columnas tendrás `N x 2` siempre que uses `mysqli_fetch_array()`, por lo tanto es mejor usar un método más específico, que podría ser `mysqli_fetch_row()` o `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`.

Por ese mismo motivo no puedes acceder desde Javascript al valor, porque el mismo se encuentraría en `response.cuentaDatos.0` o en `response.cuentaDatos.COUNT(*)` esto último porque no diste un alias a la columna de conteo en el `SELECT`.

### Falta coherencia en el código

Si Ajax espera un JSON  no puedes resolver las áreas erróneas con un `die`, porque cuando haya error tendrás un problema de JSON parse. Debes construir un array con una clave `error` y verificar eso en el `success` Ajax.

Corrigiendo ambas cosas el código quedaría así:

#### PHP

```
function notificacion(){    
    include('../../control/parcel/db.php'); 
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM reclute WHERE estado IS NULL;";
    $result=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    if(!$result){
        #Evitamos error de JSON parse 
        #OJO: se recomienda cambiar errores internos por personalizados
        $jsonstring=['error'=>mysqli_error($connection)];
    }else{
        #Puedes usar también fetch_assoc pero en ese caso debes dar un alias al SELECT
        $num_rows = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        $jsonstring=['cuentaDatos' => $num_rows[0]];
    }
    echo json_encode($jsonstring);
}
```

#### JS

Afrontamos el tema de la **coherencia** de este modo, muestro aquí solamente la parte del ´success`:

```
    success: function (response) {
        let template = "";       
        if (response.error) {
            template=response.error;
        }else{
          template=`
             <div class="cajita-notificacion" >
                <div class="caja-notificacion"> 
                    <span class="info-bd"> <span class="info-titulo">Nueva solicitud de</span> 
                    ${response.cuentaDatos}<span>
                </div>
             </div>     
                    `;        
        }
```

Se verifica si `response` tiene una clave `error`, en cuyo caso se informará al cliente de que ocurrió un error. Tu código actual no contempla posibles errores, resolviéndolos con un `die` que llevaría a un error interno del tipo JSON parse.

Hablando siempre de la **coherencia**, en jQuery las peticiones Ajax tienen un parámetro `dataType`, si lo pones así: `dataType: 'json'`, ya `response` será convertido a JSON y no necesitarás usar `JSON.parse` sobre `response`. La cuestión es que para controlar errores estarías trabajando siempre sobre el mismo tipo de objeto. Es decir, `response` sería siempre un JSON que retornó desde el servidor y como has programado coherentemente, verificando si ese objeto tiene o no una clave `error` ya sabrás a qué atenerte para alimentar a template.

De este modo el código queda blindado.

He usado además `response`, pues no tiene sentido reasignar ese dato en una nueva variable.

Comment: Gracias A.Cedano por tormarte el tiempo. Lo solucione de otra manera, pero tu solucion tiene mas coherencia. (Y)